# Simple utility to measure web site latency or user experience?

Tags: web

I used to use pings to periodically measure the latency to websites I frequent; however, that is an oversimplified picture.

I want to capture the "page load" time that I would experience if using a browser, but run it from a headless machine and identify if the problem were from DNS lookups, connection setup, a lack of bandwidth, or a bad cable.

A tool like tcpdump / wireshark would let me capture the low-level network data, but is there any sort of utility that would take a pcap file and be able to say that DNS lookups took xyz, then the web requests took abc?  I would like this to just be a tunable script that I don't have to manually run to collect the data.

That would be useful in troubleshooting connection-related issues.

Comment: Your browser is probably the best tool. The inspector in both  Chrome and FF have a network tab with such details.

Comment: Yes, but I want to do this in an automated fashion periodically so I can use that to determine if something is awry with the network and send a notification, restart a service, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that simply pinging the website in question offered the most accurate and simplest approach.  I could easily view the latency as a function of the time of the day.